# Can an ethernet device plugged into a switch block all the other ethernet devices?

Tags: network, denial-of-service

And if so, what protections are available against this kind of thing?

Comment: Ever tried feeding a single Ethernet cable back into its switch? If the switch is particularly dumb (i.e. does not utilize [STP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol)), then it'll completely fail. Fun way to shut down your uni's entire network back in the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block devices on a local network with your malicious device connected, you could do something called [ARP Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing). It can be used to do a man in the middle attack. But you can also just redirect all the packets coming from other devices to you and drop them.
You do that by using the ARP protocol and telling that your malicious device MAC address is associated with the IP address of another host (the gateway for example).

There are host-based solution to prevent this attack whoch are also available on the previous link.